# Cost of repairing old Olympus dSLR

Tags: dslr, olympus

My Olympus E520 apparently needs someone to assemble and clean mirror box, shutter, auto focus sensory and recalibrate it? Together with a CCD Clean and a Full service, I have been quoted £275.

Is that a fair price? What does a full service mean? And what does one calibrate in a digital camera?

Without the CCD Clean and Full Service... it will apparently cost me £228.

The camera works fine except now and then the auto focus doesn't work unless I reboot it. And the f-stop jumps to a high number now and then which I fix by lowering it back down.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had two mechanical film cameras serviced, which included shutter speed adjustments and full cleanings. The cost was ~$250 per camera. So, I don't think your price is completely unreasonable.

That being said, the cost of this repair is way over what this camera seems to be going for used. It came out in 2008 - it's had a good life. You could probably spend the same amount of money on a used Olympus that's a few generations newer. If it were me, I'd start camera shopping.